# IN php trying to redirect a user to link when from database after loging in

Tags: php, mysql

In php I'm trying to redirect a user to a link when querying from the database. After logging in the result just displays the url instead of redirecting to it.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submitMain']))
  {
    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $_POST['username'] = $_SESSION['username'];
    $_POST['password'] = $_SESSION['password'];  

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'"; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql); 

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row 
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result); 

    if($count == 1){ 
      $result = mysql_fetch_contents($result); // get the result set from the query

      $url = trim($result['url']); // get the url column's value

      if ($url == '') {
        echo "No url value was set!";
      } else {
        $ob_get_contents  = 'admin.php';
        echo "$ob_get_contents ";
        exit;
      }
    } else { 
      echo "Wrong Username or Password"; 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: use header('Location:xyz.php'); for more check link http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: You seem to be learning PHP. If so, it's better to not learn about the `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated. Better use `mysqli` or `PDO`. [Every documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) about any `mysql_*` function has a big red box at the top that provides you with more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ob_get_contents  = 'admin.php';
echo "$ob_get_contents ";
exit;
```

This part doesn't work. It just echoes 'admin.php'. You seem to try to do something with the `ob_get_contents` function, but it doesn't work like this. In your code, you just have a variable named `ob_get_contents`, which is unrelated to the function.

Besides, `ob_get_contents` is not the right function to get information from another page or perform a redirect to another page.

To redirect to another page, use a `Location` header:

```
header('Location:' . $url);
exit;
```

This will cause a small roundtrip to the browser. Basically you send a small result to the browser, telling it to perform a second request to the other url. But don't worry about that. This is a common solution, especially after posting information. See more information about [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: But the url is unique to every user

Comment: Ah, then use your `$url` variable in the location header (see fix in answer). I was a bit confused by that hardcoded `admin.php` in your code, and I don't really understand what you tried to achieve there.

Comment: When i use that one i get this error message 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\alchemist\index.php:210) in C:\xampp\htdocs\alchemist\index.php on line 238

Comment: That must be because you have outputted content before. This doesn't happen in the code you posted, but there may be other pieces of code that already output something. You need to send a header to perform the redirect, but you can only send headers if you haven't sent any content before (or actually, when you haven't sent the headers already).

Comment: No i haven't used header

Comment: Not header. Content. If you output anything, even a single space, `header` won't work after that.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the user, you need to set a redirection header.

To do so, you need to use the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function:

```
header("location: your location goes here"); exit();
```

For example, if your site is hosted in http://www.example.com, then to redirect to the admin area, you will user:

```
header("location: http://www.example.com/admin.php"); exit();
```

You also need to exit after redirection header.